# JMeter Plugins CMD - Graph data in csv format

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use `JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool` [http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/] to create graph data in csv format.

I want to have only 30 data points.

png file is created successfully as par the value passed for `--limit-rows` attribute.
if i try to generate csv, it simply ignores the `--limit-rows` attribute. It exports all the data in csv file.

How to export the data as per the expected data points or am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

limit-rows option is only taken into account for the graph as per:

- https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/common/src/kg/apc/charting/GraphPanelChart.java#L787

As you can see in the code exporting CSV :

- https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/common/src/kg/apc/charting/GraphPanelChart.java#L1099
- https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/common/src/kg/apc/charting/GraphModelToCsvExporter.java

Rows are just written to file ignoring the limit rows.

You can request an enhancement here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins

Comment: @ UBIK LOAD PACK, Thanks